# Rate the design of a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

My questions are very simple, but I do not know an answer.

1. There is a table `User`. The `User` has a few photos in his profile on the site. There are at least two way to store links to photo. I can serialize an array of references to a string and store it, or create another table and store pair userId-link. Which way is better?
2. The user has a unique `username` column, `email`, `phone`. Is the following code right?

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [User] ADD CONSTRAINT [LoginUk] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([Login])

   ALTER TABLE [User] ADD CONSTRAINT [EmailUk] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([Email])
   ```
3. The user has the description of one car and one of the services, which he provides. Number of services and machines will not change. I can store the vehicle details (make, photos) in the profile of the user, or I can create a new table Car and create a 1-1 relationship. Similarly, I can do with the service. Which way is better?

Comment: I prefer one row for each link.  It is a more natural fit for a relational db and means easier querying and less string parsing for you.

Comment: 1) It depends. 2) It depends. 3) It depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Actually it's better to have one photos table and have a users_photos link table, then when you add photos to other entities, there's less to change.
2. People tend to have more than one phone number. If it's a business rule that they only have one number then leave that in the application layer, not the data layer.
3. One type of thing, one table for that thing. A car is a different thing than a user.